# CuRL SSL handshake issue on Red Hat

Tags: unix, ssl, curl, redhat, handshake

I am trying to, from my Red Hat (Jenkins) server, call a REST API on another server (IBM Security Access Manager) using CuRL.

The thing is that from my Windows machine I am able to use CuRL and call the REST API successfully but not from my server (Jenkins and normal command line).
It seems that the handshake does not complete...

There is a connection between the two on the proper port. I tested this with the telnet command (telnet my.full.ip.adress 443) and even CuRL seems to connect when looking at the verbose output:

```
15:05:31.930998 * About to connect() to my.full.ip.adress port 443
15:05:31.931062 *   Trying my.full.ip.adress... connected
15:05:31.931651 * Connected to my.full.ip.adress (my.full.ip.adress) port 443
15:05:31.937510 * successfully set certificate verify locations:
15:05:31.937531 *   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
15:05:31.937629 * SSLv2, Client hello (1):
SSL connection timeout
15:06:31.987734 * Closing connection #0
```

The command im running now is:

```
-bash-3.2$ curl -k -v -H 'Content-type:application/json' -H 'Accept:application/json' --user xxx:xxx -X POST -d '{"my_key":"my_value","another_key":"another_value"}' https://my.full.ip.adress/wga/reverseproxy/
```

(and now also including '--trace-time --show-error --connect-timeout 60' for testing purposes)

The firewall logs show the following:
[image: Firewall log]
(Source and destination are the above mentioned servers)

So it seems that somewhere the handshake process goes wrong.

I done tried the following:

- Confirmed connection between the two servers on the proper port
  (SSL/443)
- Using the -1,-2,-3 arguments to force other SSL versions
- Verified the command by running it from my windows machine.

In case you are wondering:

```
-bash-3.2$ curl -V
curl 7.15.5 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap http file https ftps
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

How is it possible the handshake is not successful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved the issue. For reference for others:

As it turns out it was a routing issue. The destination server (ISAM) had a wrong routing configuration which caused the replies to void to another (sub)net.

So if you have the same issue, check your routing table :)